# Dynamically Generated Radio button form when submitted does not display data

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to create a quiz with PHP/Mysql...

I have created a form with radio buttons for answers which displays data pulled from the database as values for the radio buttons. I tried to submit the form but the result page does not show anything.

My quiz code goes as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="insertscore.php" name="cssCheckbox" id = "cssCheckbox"> 
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE (`topics` = '.NET' OR `topics` = 'PHP') ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 5"; $result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$count =1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
?>

<div class="group"> 
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $row['key_id']; ?>"><?php $row['key_id']; ?></input>
<span class="test_question"><strong><?php echo $count;?>) <?php echo $row['question']; ?>
</strong><br />

<?php   if($row['answer1'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer1']; ?>" id="chkLimit_1" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_1" ><?php echo $row['answer1']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>


<?php   if($row['answer2'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer2']; ?>" id="chkLimit_2" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_2" ><?php  echo $row['answer2']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>

<?php   if($row['answer3'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer3']; ?>" id="chkLimit_3" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_3" ><?php  echo $row['answer3']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>

<?php   if($row['answer4'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer4']; ?>" id="chkLimit_4" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_4" ><?php  echo $row['answer4']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>

<?php   if($row['answer5'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer5']; ?>" id="chkLimit_5" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_5" ><?php  echo $row['answer5']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?   ></label>

<?php   if($row['answer6'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer6']; ?>" id="chkLimit_6" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_6" ><?php  echo $row['answer6']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>

<?php   if($row['answer7'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer7']; ?>" id="chkLimit_7" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_7" ><?php  echo $row['answer7']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label> 

<?php   if($row['answer8'] != NULL){ ?>
<input type = "radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row['answer8']; ?>" id="chkLimit_8" ></input>
<label for="chkLimit_8" ><?php  echo $row['answer8']; echo "<br />"; } else {} ?></label>

<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $row['right_answer']; ?>"><?php   $row['right_answer']; ?></input>
</div>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit Your Answers" class="submit">

</form>
```

Code on submitted Page looks like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$key_id=$_POST['key_id']; echo $key_id;

$question=$_POST['question']; echo $question;

$answers=$_POST['answers']; echo $answers;

$correctanswer=$_POST['correctanswer']; echo $correctanswer;

}


foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
echo "$key --> $val<br />";
}


//var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Please let me know if anything is not clear or if I am missing anything....

Thanks,

Shank

Comment: are you sure that `insertscore.php` which i presume to be the last code snippet displayed above is "the result page that does not show anything"? can u show us the html source of the result page?

Comment: @stillstanding: I'm amazed you are asking to see more code than all the stuff he already wrote in there. :)

Comment: @stillstanding: On the result page I am trying to display the return values of the form submitted which is being done by foreach...

Comment: Update: I changed the name value in radio buttons from answers to the value similar to the value attribute. I was able to get the results but by doing so I am unable to get to desired results to save the values and store it to the database..

Comment: @Shank: your INPUT HIDDEN fields are strange, don't they miss the value attribute, moreover I don't understand why the the name attribute is written as <?php echo $row['key_id']; ?>"> and then you write <?php $row['key_id']; ?> before the </input> tag?

Comment: @marco: the hidden field for keyid is to get the keyid of the question and the answers listed on the page, so that I can carry it to the next page for calculating correct answers.. The keyid value wasn't being passed if I give a name to it so I changed it to $row['key_id']...the keyid before the ending input tag is for testing purpose it doesn't do much... I put it there for testing...

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. remove comments to `//var_dump($_POST);` and move this line at the top of the *code on submitted Page*.
2. if you still don't see anything, I think the code on submitted page is not in a file called `insertscore.php` or such file is not in same folder of your form page.

Comment: Marco: Ty for the comments... 1) I will let you know after I try the above things...   2) The code in the second block is in the insertscore.php file which is in the same folder as the form page..

Comment: I tried by moving var_dump to the top of the page and it gives the result as zero for all answers except for the last answer.(which is displayed correctly..